# Check Out Process with Braintree - Error 400 bad request - Intermittent - Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1

We have our store up and running in production, we have some customers placing orders without problem, however, everyday we got people calling and saying that they cannot place an order the system shows: (Most of them I thought was declining payment)

**Unable to place the order. Please try Again later.**

We have checked on Braintree those who says that got this error, their attempt don't even show there with any issue (e.g. Declined or something like that).

So I went to investigate and I realize that **sometimes**, not always, the payment returns 400 bad request, as you can see on image below:

[image]

Some months ago we were getting the same issue for ALL orders and based on some other instructions we have changed our **sales_invoice_grid** table adding one new column as you can see on image below: (It fixed most of the issues)

[image]

But making many tests today I could see that sometimes it happens again. I **have no prefix** in our Magento database installation.

Some extra info:

PHP Version 5.6.28

Server: Centos 7 (PVHVM)

I have Apache + NGINX + Varnish running together.

Checkout only with Braintree activated.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need to enable debug mode for Braintree and check responses from Braintree gateway, perhaps it returns errors.

Also, you need to use xdebug and set a breakpoint  in https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement.php#L71 or https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/GuestPaymentInformationManagement.php#L83 for guest customers to find the original exception message.

Magento team has an issue related to exceptions messages for place order action from storefront - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6246, but it has been fixed only for develop branch and doesn't available for 2.1.x versions.