# Braintree payment returns "Unable to place order. Please try again later."

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods

When I go to checkout I got this error (with Braintree Sandbox mode): "Unable to place order. Please try again later.".

I already did everything in https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5902, removed my SQL tables prefixes and so on.

Now, what's really strange to me is: **I only get this error with some products.**

Furthermore, my co-dev can't order anything at all!
So, what could be the problem? All products have same configuration.

Help, it's pretty urgent!

[image: This is my console]

Comment: Check your browser errors, also see my answer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146828/check-out-process-with-braintree-error-400-bad-request-intermittent-magent/146888#146888, it will help you to find an original error

Comment: @jonijones I added a screenshot of my console, problem should be with /rest/default/V1/carts/...

Comment: yes, but this response doesn't show a original exception message and as I described in my answer, you need to use xdebug to find original exception

Comment: @jonijones are there other fixes I could try? My provider does not let me install xdebug

Comment: You can try to use `var_dump()` or logging